# Pass more than 255 arguments to a function

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments

I'm simply passing my arguments from `def` statement to `def` statement. I did not know there was a limit for the amount of arguments that you can pass. I'm assuming arguments are variables. I need to be able to pass more than 255. Can someone help me in layman terms how to work around "more than 255 arguments".  Thanks!

Code:

```
def a():
  "Things happening"
  variable1
  b(variable1)

def b(variable1):
  "Things happening"
  variable2
  c(variable1, variable2)

def c(variable1, variable2):
  "Things happening"
  variable3
  d(variable1, variable2, variable3)
.
.
.
def z5(variable1,...variable256):
  print result

main()
```

Comment: Instead of a slew of arguments, why not just pass 1 argument that is a list? If I saw an API that had a function where I had to pass 255 arguments, I would literally print out the entire code on physical paper, and throw that library in the garbage.

Comment: what is the real code? You have 256 different functions, that are all called each by each with all variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python purposefully prevents you from passing more than 255 arguments because code that does so is very unweildy and hard to maintain.  If a function needs that many arguments (or anything close to that number), it means there is a flaw in the design.

If you truly need +255 different values, then you should put them all in a list and make your function accept that instead:

```
def z5(list_of_values):
    ...

z5([val1, val2, val3, ...])
```

Comment: Why? What's better with putting the values in a list before sending them to the function? Is there any fundamental difference?

Answer (score 8):

In python 3.7 you can now pass more than 255 arguments.

See here:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html

https://bugs.python.org/issue12844

https://bugs.python.org/issue18896