# Pyspark: Adding new column has the sum of rows values for more than 255 column

Tags: pyspark, sum, arguments, python-3.6

I need to find the sum of row values for around 900 column I applied the function in this link [Spark - Sum of row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360540/spark-sum-of-row-values/36361941#36361941)

```
from functools import reduce

def superSum(*cols):
   return reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, cols)

add = udf(superSum)

df.withColumn('total', add(*[df[x] for x in df.columns])).show()
```

but i got this error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1005.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***********\pyspark\worker.py", line 218, in main
  File "***********\pyspark\worker.py", line 147, in read_udfs
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: more than 255 arguments
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass more than 255 arguments to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766076/pass-more-than-255-arguments-to-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give same error superSum functions but code below is worked, I guess udf functions not working with more than 255 arguments.
python3

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
import findspark
findspark.init() # replace with your spark path
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    Row(**{str(i):0 for i in range(300)})
])

df \
    .withColumn('total', reduce(operator.add, map(F.col, df.columns))).show()
```

Comment: @ hamza tuna after apply your code and save the resulting DF I obtained this error '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
********\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in _get_connection(self)
    851         try:
--> 852             connection = self.deque.pop()
    853         except IndexError:

IndexError: pop from an empty deque                        Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:54179)
'

Comment: I did that and restart my PC and this action still appear and also get the following message 'ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Comment: pyspark  --num-executors 20 --executor-memory 12G --executor-cores 5 --driver-memory 16G --driver-cores 3

Comment: updated answer. I put all code and its working correctly. Are you sure to you have running cluster. You checked your spark web ui? You really have 20 executors with 12 G ram. This means you have least 20 computer with 16 G ram

Comment: I created spark session as follow     'SparkSession.builder\
    .master("local")\
    .appName("my_app")\
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")\
    .getOrCreate()

Comment: concerning the pyspark configuration. I work on a server and I  faced some proplem like OOM error and after wrote this i didn't counter OOM yet

Comment: Can you try without  --num-executors 20 --executor-memory 12G --executor-cores 5 --driver-memory 16G --driver-cores 3 – this